# Unity saturation for 2D images

Tags: graphics, unity-game-engine, import, colors, pixel

My friend and I are making a game, and when I upload his 2D images into Unity, the colors are quite under-saturated. Is this possible to remedy?

The filter is Point, and format is Compressed. I tried 16 bits and True Color, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with gamma correction. However, this could be anywhere. Maybe, the image is originally under-saturated.

Comment: What is the file format?

Comment: It's a PNG. It shows up beautifully in the folder preview. Then gets bland when thrown into unity.

Comment: do you use alpha blending? may be your images are just transparent ... try to change background to white and black to see if behavior changes to check for this

Comment: It does it with the non-transparent ones too. The background I'm using is full color without any transparent parts, and that too is a dull saturation